# Query github issues when creating a new question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When a user creates a question he get's a list of questions that might already answer his or her question. Sometimes the problem might not be reported on Stack Overflow but there could already exist an issue on Github for the problem.

Github provides an API for searching issues. How would it be if also this issues were queried when creating a new question. The user could get the solution much earlier than he would waiting for the answer on Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately Github has a rate limit for the API but maybe they would loosen the limit up for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange needs to query GitHub for issues, that should be up to the user who is posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

What about projects that aren't hosted on GitHub? Should we also query the hundreds of other issue trackers that exist out there on the web? Beyond Bitbucket and other services similar to GitHub, there are plenty of large frameworks that host their own source code and/or run their own issue trackers—e.g., Mozilla, Qt, The Gnu Compiler Collection, the Mono Project, etc. Even companies that write proprietary software (e.g., Microsoft) often have online bug trackers.

This proposal simply doesn't scale. Therefore, we only search *content on Stack Overflow*. If you want to search content outside of Stack Overflow, there is already a perfectly good tool for it: search engines. A company in Mountain View has designed a particularly good one. It is called Google; perhaps you've heard of it?

Less sardonically, searching on GitHub falls into the more general expectation that you do some basic research on your own *before* asking a question on Stack Overflow. When you do that broad Internet search, it ensures a couple of things:

1. That you're not asking a silly question that would be easily answered by 30 seconds of research (not that these are strictly off-topic, but they tend not to be very well-received by the community),
2. That you have a sufficient amount of background knowledge to write a good question, and
3. That you are able to locate *all* information relevant to your problem that might be out there, whether hosted on GitHub or not.

Beyond that, I should also point out that the mere fact that there is an issue open on GitHub (or anywhere else) for a particular problem **does not** make the question off-topic or in any way inappropriate for Stack Overflow. As such, we don't want to *discourage* people from asking these types of questions. It is perfectly reasonable to ask the question and have someone post an answer linking to the issue on GitHub (or wherever it may be hosted). Putting it another way: we don't mind duplicating the information here on Stack Overflow; in fact, it dovetails nicely with our goal to build a comprehensive database of solutions to programming problems. A bug with a library is a programming problem that we would like to have a question about and an answer to.